# Fluid simulation in moving object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, fluid-simulation

I am working on animation in which I have moving object filled with liquid. Problem is that liquid is reaching over the mesh. Scaling does not fix the problem since the liquid does not follow up the animation.

Any idea on how to fix this[image]?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information detailing how you set up your project, and your fluid and domain settings.

Comment: This question could benefit from a .blend, since there are a lot of settings that would need to be replicated to create the example gifs.

Answer (score 2):

For liquids contained within a mesh you should always ensure that the ‘container’ has thickness (either by modelling the thickness or by adding a Solidify modifier. You should then ensure that the Resolution of the fluid domain is set high enough so that each cell in the simulation is smaller than the minimum thickness of the container. This will ensure that the fluid does not protrude outside the mesh.

For an cleaner boundary (eg, if the container is transparent) between the fluid and its container (to stop them intersecting) you can add a Boolean modifier to the fluid to remove the parts that intersect into the container mesh.