# Sand won't stay in hour-glass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to make this sand-in-hourglass effect in Blender and I set it all up but the grains don't stay in the hourglass at the end. They collide correctly in the center but they just fall through (or if I change the glass to "Passive" then then about 50% stay). I have tried every idea I can think of.
[image]

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110434/fluid-simulation-in-moving-object

Comment: Thanks, my scene is kind of different: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/amxnf5bf39r9iz3/hour_glass_testing.blend.zip?dl=0]

Comment: So adding thickness doesn't help? Btw please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for uploading .blend files :)

Comment: tried thickness in many forms but still screws up.

Comment: ok so I think I just finally figured it out! I have the steps per second as the default 60; it seems to only work at about 800?